# jQuery onclick refreshes the fields

Tags: jquery, jsf

I have a jsf dropdown that decides the fields to be populated onchange using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //hide all in target div
    $("div","div#fields").hide();
    $("#dbform\\:dbfields").change(function() {
        // hide previously shown in target div
        $("div", "div#fields").hide();
        var value = $("#dbform\\:dbfields").val();
        $("div#" + value).show();
    });
});
```

But when I click on the submit button in the `"div#" + value` div tag, the JSF page refreshes and the controls disappear throwing an error saying fields cannot be empty. Not sure how to overcome this. I want the button to submit the event and populate other fields.

Comment: What makes you think it's *refreshing* the page rather than, as would be expected, *submitting* the form?

Comment: Submit event is not getting triggered.The input fields in the div tag gets hidden and throws a validation error saying the fields cannot be empty.

Comment: Did you verify if there is a validation error occurring on the server?  If values being submitted on the form are not valid then the action event of the submit button will not be triggered.  The jQuery ready function will execute after every server postback which explains why the div is being hidden anyway.

Comment: @maple: The validation error is not on the server side. Like you said the ready function will execute on every server postback, is there any way that i can remove that dependency. i tried creating a javascript function and triggering it onchange of dropdown but the show and hide functions doesnt seem to work in that case. Stuck with this issue from long. Please help.